# Couchbase N1QL query Connection failed

Tags: java, mysql, maven, couchbase

I'm customizing couchbase sql importer open source code in maven project.
this is my code.

```
CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
            .socketConnectTimeout((int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(45))
            .connectTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(60))
            .build();
cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env,"couchbase-dev.thisisdmg.com:8091");
bucket = cluster.openBucket(bucketName);

com.couchbase.client.java.query.Statement statement = select("*").from(i("sales_agent")).where("meta(t).id = 'appointments_appointment:1'").limit(50).offset(0);
JsonObject placeholderValues = JsonObject.create().put("age", 22);

for (N1qlQueryRow row : bucket.query(N1qlQuery.parameterized(statement, placeholderValues))) {
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

When I send the query to server, I'm getting bellow error.

```
Mar 28, 2017 4:40:28 PM com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$2 onSuccess
WARNING: [null][QueryEndpoint]: Could not connect to remote socket.
Mar 28, 2017 4:40:28 PM com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint$2 onSuccess
WARNING: [null][QueryEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint, retrying with delay 4096 MILLISECONDS: 
com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information: couchbase-dev.thisisdmg.com/5.9.216.200:8093
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help me, how can I fix this problem.

Comment: I'm using couchbase java sdk 2.4.3. 
   
<dependency>
           <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
           <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.3</version>
       </dependency>

Comment: This looks as if the remote end is inaccessible, have you checked?

Comment: Hi dash, Thanks for your reply, I'm not sure, how can i check it?

Comment: maybe ping it or try and log in manually?

Comment: I tried ping to the server.
C:\Users\Meteoric>ping couchbase-dev.thisisdmg.com -t

Pinging couchbase-dev.thisisdmg.com [5.9.216.200] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Comment: Perhaps this is the root of your problem. (Not necessarily, because not every server is set up to respond to ping.)

Comment: How can I fix the problem?
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/install-ports.html
I read this article, but I'm not sure, How do i do.

Comment: If this is someone else's server, then contact them and ask them why they are down; if it's your own, then serverfault would be the place to ask rather than SO, I think.

Comment: 'ping' is not the best way to test connectivity. The Couchbase server provides a REST API, which by default is on port 8091. You can test connectivity with the server by doing a REST call. E.g., for my local machine, I do: "curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools", or I can just enter the URL "http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools" into a browser.